# Double Click Event on TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I cannot believe I am asking such a simple question here!

I have a winform C# desktop app.

I have a `tablelayoutpanel` - the `dock` property is set to `Filled`.
It has 3 rows.

In the top row I have added another tablelayoutpanel.
It also has the `dock` property set to `Filled`.
The number of columns is 3.
In column 1 there is a picturebox control.
In column 3 there is a label control.

I have written code for the double-click event and MouseDoubleClickEvent for the picturebox, label and 2nd TableLayoutPanel.
I have set a breakpoint in both events.

I run the app, i double-click on picture, label and/or tablelayoutpanel but the breakpoint is never hit.

I can post code if required but it is so simple i have not done so (yet).

1. Is this a known issue?
2. Am I missing something obvious?
3. Am I totally useless?

Thanks

My Code:

I have this module event declared:

```
private void Caption_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
    else
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}
```

This are hooked up in the designer of that Form

```
tlpCaption.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Caption_DoubleClick);

lblCaption.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Caption_DoubleClick);

picLogo.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Caption_DoubleClick);
```

Comment: Did you hook them up to the events? (for example, your picture should have a "on_click" event handler, that points to the method in the code behind ...)

Comment: Where have you set the breakpoint?

Comment: try a clean solution and then a rebuild! if this doenst work try restart visual studio..  (could be something with cache)

Comment: hi, on the 1st '{'.  But the form is not maximised or normalized (is that a word?)

Comment: @lordkain I was kinda hoping that would be the case. I shall do a clean/Rebuild and report back.  thanks

Comment: put breakpoint on the if and not on the { that should help :)

Comment: I have done all that has been suggested still no joy.  Is there an issue maybe with nested TableLayputPanels? (I a genuinely clutching at straws here)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson : did you try setting breakpoint on the if?

Comment: yes, and just to make sure i set a breakpoint on every line of code in the event :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson : see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I hade one tableLayoutPanel , everything works out good. debugger stops. But when I add another tableLayoutPanel in the first tableLayoutPanel and moved the picturebox the debugger wont reach my code. I hade same probnlem as you. remove the events and add them again solves my problem..

1. comment out Caption_DoubleClick function and remove bindings in code
2. rebuild code with no errors
3. add new event by designer and verify that the debuigger stops here
4. move code from commented out to this method

Comment: Hi, it was nice attempt but for me it did not work. All a pain. Thanks for your time though..

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem...something is "corrupt" in your project.  This isn't a bug with nested TableLayoutPanels or anything.  Sorry.

[image]

Comment: lol - probably! :) I am re-designing to get what i want. Thanks for looking at it though :)

Comment: No problem.  Sometimes it's good to just get feedback and know you're not crazy or doing anything wrong...

Comment: Oh I am sure I am crazy :)